# In mouse hooking, the wheel delta is always 0

Tags: c++, winapi

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK mouseProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam){
  if(wParam == WM_MOUSEWHEEL){
    std::cout << "wheel: " << GET_WHEEL_DELTA_WPARAM(wParam) << std::endl;
  }else{
    MOUSEHOOKSTRUCT* mouselparam = (MOUSEHOOKSTRUCT*)lParam;
    std::cout << "etc: " << wParam << " - " << mouselparam->pt.x << "x" << mouselparam->pt.y << std::endl;
  }
  return CallNextHookEx(NULL, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    HHOOK hhkLowLevelMouse = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE_LL, mouseProc, 0, 0);

    MSG msg;
    while (!GetMessage(&msg, NULL, NULL, NULL)) {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    UnhookWindowsHookEx(hhkLowLevelMouse);

    return 0;
}
```

This is the full code.

"etc:" works perfectly as I intended.

"wheel:" always outputs 0.

am i missing something?

Using `HIWORD` instead of `GET_WHEEL_DELTA_WPARAM` gives the same result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`GET_WHEEL_DELTA_WPARAM()` only works with the `wParam`  of a real `WM_MOUSEWHEEL` window message, not the `wParam` of a `WH_MOUSE_LL` hook.

In the hook, the `wParam` is just the message identifier by itself, nothing more. ALL of the mouse details are stored in a `MSLLHOOKSTRUCT` struct pointed by the `lParam`. Which you attempted to look at for all mouse messages *other than* `WM_MOUSEWHEEL`, but you are looking at the wrong struct (`MOUSEHOOKSTRUCT` is used by `WH_MOUSE`, not `WH_MOUSE_LL`).

Per the [LowLevelMouseProc callback function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/ms644986(v=vs.85)) documentation:

> - `wParam` [in]
>   Type: `WPARAM`
>
>   The identifier of the mouse message. This parameter can be one of the following messages: `WM_LBUTTONDOWN`, `WM_LBUTTONUP`, `WM_MOUSEMOVE`, `WM_MOUSEWHEEL`, `WM_MOUSEHWHEEL`, `WM_RBUTTONDOWN`, or `WM_RBUTTONUP`.
> - `lParam` [in]
>   Type: `LPARAM`
>
>   A pointer to an [`MSLLHOOKSTRUCT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644970(v=vs.85)) structure.

And the [MSLLHOOKSTRUCT structure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-msllhookstruct) documentation:

> `mouseData`
> Type: `DWORD`
>
> If the message is `WM_MOUSEWHEEL`, **the high-order word of this member is the wheel delta**. The low-order word is reserved. A positive value indicates that the wheel was rotated forward, away from the user; a negative value indicates that the wheel was rotated backward, toward the user. One wheel click is defined as `WHEEL_DELTA`, which is 120.

Try this instead:

```cpp
LRESULT CALLBACK mouseProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam){
    if (nCode == HC_ACTION) {
        MSLLHOOKSTRUCT* mouselparam = (MSLLHOOKSTRUCT*)lParam;
        if (wParam == WM_MOUSEWHEEL) {
            short delta = HIWORD(mouselparam->mouseData); 
            // alternatively, GET_WHEEL_DELTA_WPARAM() would also work here:
            // short delta = GET_WHEEL_DELTA_WPARAM(mouselparam->mouseData);
            std::cout << "wheel: " << delta << std::endl;
        }else{
            std::cout << "etc: " << wParam << " - " << mouselparam->pt.x << "x" << mouselparam->pt.y << std::endl;
        }
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(NULL, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! `MSLLHOOKSTRUCT` worked perfectly for me.

Comment: thanks remy, got the right struct